# Questions regarding transformation in bacterial cells

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, bacteriology, transformation

First off, in transformation the donor DNA aligns itself with the complementary bases in the recipient DNA.

Now a "perfect" alignment of the donor DNA ( Sorry if my terminologies are incorrect ) would mean that an exact replica of the donor DNA fragment already exists in the recipient DNA. If such is the case no genetic recombination will take place but genetic recombination is observed, this is the part where I get confused.

If the DNA fragment is aligning itself with the donor DNA and and causing a genetic recombination, then obviously the donor DNA fragment should contain some variation from the recipient's DNA. This would mean that the alignment of the DNA fragment isn't perfect and not every base in DNA fragment can form a complementary base pairs with the recipient DNA. ( Again sorry for usage of improper terminology as I'm a new student who just started an introductory course pertaining to microbiology ).

Now the problem is -

1. Shouldn't it be energetically unfavorable for the donor DNA fragment to replace the original DNA as the original one should be able to form complementary base pairs with the entirety of the recipient DNA while the donor DNA can do so only with a part of the recipient DNA.

   **After thinking about this, I thought of an assumption to explain this. The RecA protein involved in transformation is somehow forcing this process to happen. The thing is how? I have zero knowledge of enzyme chemistry and can't understand how this could possibly happen?
   So is this assumption correct? If so is there any reference material explaining how RecA protein could be doing this?**
2. This brings me to the second issue. This newly created DNA should now have many irregularities, how are they fixed?

   After some thinking, I came to the conclusion that as RecA proteins are involved in DNA repair, the RecA protein simply fixes the irregularities. Is this line of thinking correct?

**In short, I have assumed that a RecA protein is causing a DNA fragment which can not form complementary base pairs with the entirety of recipient DNA to be accepted in the recipient DNA, following which the irregularities that arise are also fixed by RecA. Is this line of thinking correct?**

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and delete or [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, questions must be focused enough to be answerable on this site — we cannot recreate textbook chapters! We also expect you to do research and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Your questions are both too general and based on imagination rather than looking up readily available facts. Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: Too many notes! Too many notes!

Comment: Transformation is done using plasmids right? So why are you concerned about recombination with the 'primary' bacterial genome?

Comment: @Roni Saiba im talking about the transformation as observed by Frederick Griffith's experiment in 1928 using virulent and non virulent strains of Streptococcus pneumoniae. Am I mistaken and does this type of transformation happen only through Plasmids?

Comment: @David im new to this website, can you please explain what are the " notes " you are referring to? ( I'm sorry if this somehow sounded rude, English isn't my first language )

Comment: Anish. Sorry for being obtuse. Welcome to the site. It's a good idea for new users to read the [Help on Asking Questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help). You should make sure that you are asking a single question about a problem in biology and set it out so we are clear what it is. This is a question and answer site, it is not a place to ask for comments on your general thoughts or difficulties with a topic.

Comment: @AnishKumar it is also good to have a question title that exactly states your actual question. For example you could ask "how does a completely foreign DNA recombine with genomic DNA during transformation/HGT". Also, as others suggested do not ask multiple questions (and ask one precise question) but it is good to provide a good background as you tried to do.